# How to rotate part in Eagle (schematic view) using hotkeys only?

Tags: eaglecad

I'm fairly new to eagle. So far i was unable to figure out how to rotate a part in the schematic editor using keyboard shortcuts only.

I'm using 7.5.0 on Linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple way with the mouse rather than the keyboard.

When you have a part selected with the move tool, simply right click and it will rotate 90 degrees. Also, if you are holding the shift key when you right click, the part will rotate in the opposite direction.

This works on Windows, so I assume it will work on Linux.

Comment: There seem to be two modes. Sometimes the the mouse context menu opens but i was also able to rotate it once. I don't understand why i sometimes get the menu instead.

Comment: @Jotschi You'll get the menu if the part isn't selected for moving. When you click on a part with the move tool, it is not necessarily immediately selected if there is some ambiguity as to which part or wire to select (e.g. two very close together). In this case you will see a notice at the bottom left corner saying to click again to select.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, it works on Mac also, both cases as described by @Tom Carpenter